# Managed entity doesn't show as managed

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

The problem that I'm having is that inside a bundle I am setting the user on a token to pass to the security context. This authenticates me and that is working fine. However whenever I retrieve that user from the security context within another bundle by doing this:

```
$this->getUser()
```

I get the correct entity, all data is there, however Doctrine says it's not a managed entity.

The code which sets the user on the token is as follows:

```
    protected function logUserIn($userId, $name, $locale, $roles, $permissions)
    {
        $csbAuthUser = new User($name, $userId, $roles, $locale, $permissions);
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
            $csbAuthUser,
            null,
            'csb',
            $roles
        );

        if ($this->csbAuthEntityString) {
            $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository($this->csbAuthEntityString)-    >findOneBy(array(
                'connectSBUser' => $userId,
            )
        );

        $user->setUsername($name);
        $user->setRoles($roles);
        $user->setLocale($locale);
        $user->setPermissions($permissions);

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
            $user,
            null,
            'csb',
            $roles
        );
    }
    $this->securityContext->setToken($token);
```

This is a problem because everytime I want to update anything that has a connection with the user entity Doctrine says it has found a new entity in the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an instance of `User` either way - but the default user you're creating at the top of the method is not a managed object.  The entity that comes back from your entity manager would be.

What is the value of `$this->csbAuthEntityString` and are you sure its making it into that IF statement? I'd double check that with some debug output.

Comment: I have checked multiple times, it is going into the IF statement. The    `$this->csbAuthEntityString` is a parameter and it's set to the value of the class that I want. This is working, I have checked it multiple times. I have checked if the user entity is managed when setting the token by getting the user from the token by doing `$this->securityContext->getToken()->getUser()` and Doctrine returns that it is indeed managed. I am using two different bundles. Could it maybe be that because I am editing the entity in another bundle that it's not properly set up in the other one?

Comment: If you're getting the user from the token / the session, you'll most likely need to `merge` the entity back into the entity manager.  check [this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/cookbook/entities-in-session.html#merging-entity-into-an-entitymanager) resource